# After Three Days of Experimenting and Searching, I STILL Can't Get .getValue Function to Work

Tags: function

Sorry for the long subject line, but this site wouldn't accept a more concise statement.

I have a Google Sheet, that has nothing more than my name in Cell A1.

Then I went to Tools / Script Editor, and have a "Code.gs" script that says:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log("We're in the function.");

  var ss = Spreadsheet.App.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var valueOfCell = sheet.getRange(1,1).getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log("Value of Cell is '" + valueOfCell + "'.");
}
```

When I edit my very simple sheet, and check the log (View / Logs), I get:

```
[19-02-28 08:58:10:182 CST] We're in the function.
```

That's it. I've tried every permutation I can think of or suss from three days of web-searching, and I simply can not make the .getValue() (or .getDisplayValue()) work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

/Kent

Answer (score 0):

"Spreadsheet.App" should be "SpreadsheetApp".

Additional permutations that work:

```
Logger.log("We're in the function.");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var valueOfCell = ss.getRange(1,1).getDisplayValue;
```

and

```
Logger.log("We're in the function.");
var valueOfCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(1,2).getDisplayValue();
```

and

```
Logger.log("We're in the function.");
var valueOfCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,2).getDisplayValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

After four days, I think I finally understand some of this. For others as dense as I, I leave this documentation here:

*Spreadsheet* is the "workbook", the collection of *Sheet* tabs
*Sheet* is the individual tab'd sheet in a *Spreadsheet* "workbook".

Seems like simple enough information, but I couldn't find this documented anywhere.

*SpreadsheetApp* is the Class, the "parent" of all the Spreadsheets. While probably not technically accurate, for purposes of my thinking, I think of "SpreadsheetApp" as being the "Sheets" application within Google Docs, as opposed to "Docs" or "Slides".

So,

```
var ThisApp = SpreadsheetApp;
// Sets the variable "ThisApp" to "SpreadsheetApp", which I guess is the name/identification of the spreadsheet app.

var TheActiveWorkBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
// Sets "TheActiveWorkBook" to the identifier for the current collection of sheets (collection of tabs within a spreadsheet).

var TheActiveWorkBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// Identical to above; just a different name for it.

var ActiveWorkBookName = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
// Sets the variable to the *name* of the workbook/spreadsheet (like, "Fred's Spreadsheet").

var ActiveSheetInWB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();getActiveSheet();
// Sets the variable to the identifier of the active tab in the spreadsheet.

var ActiveSheetInWB = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();getActiveSheet();
// Identical to above.

var ActiveSheetInWB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// Identical to above. The active sheet is the active sheet, regardless of whether we know the active spreadsheet, so the extra step of including the active spreadsheet, as we did in the previous two examples, is unnecessary. (The system knows that the active spreadsheet is the one that contains the active sheet.)

var ActiveSheetInWB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
// Gets the *name* of the sheet, as it shows on that sheet's tab.

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ActiveSheetInWB = sheet.getName();
// Shortens the long "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()" to a short reference to save typing in subsequent uses. Otherwise identical to above example.
```

I think I'm finally getting the hang of this....